# SVM : Why can we set 1 in the hyperplane equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I am reading the Wikipedia article about SVM and there is something I don't understand. When they say:

> These hyperplanes can be described by the equations
>
> $$ wx - b=1 $$  and
>
> $$wx - b=-1$$

I was wondering where does the +1 and -1 come from?

I found two papers which explain that this is an arbitrary choice:

> We can write the following equations for the support hyperplanes:
>
> $$w^T x  = b + \delta    $$ 
>    $$w^T x = b − \delta   $$ 
>   We now note that we have over-parameterized the problem: 
>   if we scale w, b and $\delta$ by a constant factor $\alpha$, 
>   the equations for x are still satisfied.
>
> **To remove this  ambiguity we will require that $\delta$ = 1, this sets the scale of the  problem**, i.e. if we measure distance in millimeters or meters

[Source](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/classnotes/papers_class/SVM.pdf)

but I don't understand what he means when he says "this sets the scale of the problem"

and

> Note that if the equation
>   $f(x) = wx + b$ defines a discriminant function
>
> (so that the output is > $sgn(f(x))$),
>
> then
>   the hyperplane $cwx + cb$ defines the same discriminant function for any $c > 0$.
>
> **Thus we have the freedom to choose the scaling of $w$** so that $min_{x_i}
> |wx_i + b| = 1$.

[Source](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/iaml/docs/svm.pdf)

but I don't understand why he introduces  $min_{x_i}
|wx_i + b| = 1$.

My understanding is that we can do it because variables $w$, $b$ and $\delta$ are kind of linked together.

Can we change the Wikipedia definition and say

> These hyperplanes can be described by the equations  $$ wx - b= 2 $$ 
>   and   $$wx - b=- 2$$

or is this incorrect and so we must say that :

> These hyperplanes can be described by the equations  $$ 2wx - 2b= 2 $$ 
>   and   $$2wx - 2b=- 2$$

Could you clarify this for me?

Comment: For reader's information: the Wikipedia reference is: [Support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) .

Answer (score 14):

Very simply, if you choose any number other than 1, you can simply scale it away again. Consider
$$
\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}-b=\pm\delta
$$
Now, divide both sides of the equation by $\delta$, and we get
$$
\left(\frac1\delta\mathbf{w}\right)\cdot\mathbf{x}-\frac{b}{\delta}=\pm1
$$
Which means that we can define $\mathbf{\hat w}=\frac1\delta\mathbf{w}$ and $\hat b=\frac{b}{\delta}$, and we have
$$
\mathbf{\hat w}\cdot\mathbf{x}-\hat b=\pm1
$$
And because the goal is to minimise $\|\mathbf{w}\|$ (in order to maximise the size of the margin, $\frac2{\|\mathbf{w}\|}$), it doesn't matter if we scale $\mathbf{w}$ by some constant such as $\delta$ first - and so, we can use $\mathbf{\hat w}$ in place of $\mathbf{w}$, and the choice of $\delta$ is irrelevant (aside from needing to be a positive real number).

Since it's irrelevant, might as well make it the simplest possible positive real number, 1.

As for why it "sets the scale" of the problem, think of it this way: changing $\delta$ would change the scaling of $\mathbf{w}$ (that is, choosing $\delta=2$ would make $\mathbf{w}$ twice as big, for example). And so, just as changing $\delta$ changes the scale, so too does setting $\delta$ set the scale - it keeps it fixed, rather than having it vary from instance to instance.

Comment: Thanks Glen....!

Comment: Perfect! You cleared my confusions. +1

Comment: *"it doesn't matter if we scale $\mathbf{w}$ by some constant such as $\delta$"* What makes you think that $\delta$ is a *constant*??

Comment: *"and because the goal is to minimise $\|\mathbf{w}\|$ "* No, the goal is to minimize $\mathbf{\|\hat w\|}$, which is $\frac{\mathbf{\|\hat w\|}}{\delta}$. Minimizing $\|\mathbf{w}\|$ is the goal when $\delta$ is assumed to be equal to 1, not in actuality.

Comment: @mehdicharife - if $\delta$ isn't a constant, then we don't have support hyperplanes parallel to the main hyperplane - either the support hyperplanes will not be parallel, or they won't be hyperplanes (because they're not "flat"). And because $\delta$ is constant, minimising $\|\mathbf{w}\|$ is the same as minimising $\|\mathbf{\hat{w}}\|$

Comment: @GlenO Why do you assume we have support hyperplanes that are parallel to the main hyperplane? That's part of what we are trying to prove.

Comment: @mehdicharife - ummm... no, that's not what we're trying to prove. Have a look at the Wikipedia page on the topic. To quote it, "If the training data is linearly separable, we can select two parallel hyperplanes that separate the two classes of data, so that the distance between them is as large as possible." - two parallel hyperplanes. If they're not parallel, then they will intersect somewhere, and that defeats the whole point of the hyperplanes, which is to separate data into two groups.

Comment: @GlenO Why are you then assuming that $\delta$ being constant is a necessary condition for having "support hyperplanes parallel to the main hyperplane"?

Comment: @mehdicharife - because if $\delta$ varies with $\mathbf{x}$ (which is the only thing it could vary by to make it not able to be treated as a constant), then either it will vary linearly, which produces non-parallel hyperplanes, or it will vary nonlinearly, which produces surfaces that aren't hyperplanes because they're not flat.

Comment: @GlenO *"which is the only thing it could vary by to make it not able to be treated as a constant"* ummm... no, $\delta$ varies as an argument of the function that we want to minimize/maximize, which is not dependent on $x$.